# Java Date sorting method?

Tags: java, sorting, date, calendar, date-format

I have an String array of dates in the format ex:'2010-05-04 11:26:46 +0530'.
How can I check whether a particular date in the array is > today?

thanks

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

df.parse(datearray[i]).after(new Date())
```

Comment: I have to admit, that this matches only dates > now(), not dates > today(), but this should not be too hard to accomplish.