# StackOverflowError while sorting dates recursively

Tags: java, android, sorting, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a recursive function which takes a List of Events and sort them by their date. It has worked just fine, but today I got a crash report on Google play developer console. A StackOverflowError is thrown.

So, my question is, does someone know why this is happening and what to do to avoid it?

My sort function:

```
public class SortEventDates {

    public List<Event> sortDates(List<Event> eventList) {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, ix, j;

        // Sorting
        for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size() - 1; i++) {
            a = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i).getDate().split("/")[2]); // <--Row 18
            b = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i+1).getDate().split("/")[2]);
            // Sorting years
            if (a > b) {
                Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                sortDates(eventList);
            } else if (a == b) {
                c = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i).getDate().split("/")[0]);
                d = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i+1).getDate().split("/")[0]);
                // Sorting months
                if (c > d) {
                    Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                    sortDates(eventList); // <-- Row 30
                } else if (c == d) {
                    e = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i).getDate().split("/")[1]);
                    f = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i+1).getDate().split("/")[1]);
                    // Sorting days
                    if (e > f) {
                        Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                        sortDates(eventList); // <-- Row 37
                    } else if (e == f) {
                        g = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i).getTime().split(":")[0]);
                        h = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i+1).getTime().split(":")[0]);
                        // Sorting hours
                        if (g > h) {
                            Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                            sortDates(eventList);
                        } else if (g == h) {
                            ix = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i).getTime().split(":")[1]);
                            j = Integer.valueOf(eventList.get(i+1).getTime().split(":")[1]);
                            // Sorting minutes
                            if (ix > j) {
                                Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                                sortDates(eventList);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return eventList;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Splitter.fastSplit(Splitter.java:46)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1842)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1824)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:18)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:37)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:37)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:37)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:30)
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:37)
    ...
    ...
    at app.android.arret.java.services.SortEventDates.sortDates(SortEventDates.java:30)
    at app.android.arret.java.activity.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:119)
    at app.android.arret.java.activity.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:24)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: Modify your unit test to contain more Events in eventList?

Comment: cause is your function has never returned and going deeper and deeper. Check the logic of method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Date sorting method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786379/java-date-sorting-method)

Answer (score 3):

You are aware of [Java Comparables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), right?

Basic usage:

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {

    private Date date;

    public Event(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
        // Constructor
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event e) {
        if (getDate() == null || e.getDate() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return getDate().compareTo(e.getDate());
    }
}
```

And then call this to sort your list:

```
Collections.sort(eventList);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify your model, you can do the following:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        if (e1.getDate() == null || e2.getDate() == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return e1.getDate().compareTo(e2.getDate());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never returning from your recirsive calls .As per stack trace of the program on your input set once you recursively call your function it never returns

```
if (c > d) {
                    Collections.swap(eventList, i, i+1);
                    sortDates(eventList); // <-- Row 30
                }
```

This function will be called infinitely and will lead to stack overflow.
You need to provide a reaturn condition from these calls.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a return statement at the bottom of the method. As soon one if-statement is false it will continue with next event and in the end it will return the eventList

Comment: What I mean is in the first iteration you swap date a and b on line 29 and co-incidently you swap the list again at line 36 because of their days. You reinitialised "i" to 0 , thus this loop goes on infinitely in swapping a and b

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Java 8 streams for sorting like this:

```
Comparator<Event> sortByDate = new Comparator<Event>() {
    public int compare(Event left, Event right) {
        if (left.getDate().isBefore(right.getDate())) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } 
    }
};

Collections.sort(events, sortByDate);
```

Comment: You actually forgot the case in which two `Event`s happen on the same date, which returns `0`. Leaving that out would result in an indefinite shifting of `Event`s with the same date. It's better to use the supplied `.compareTo ();` method since it handles the comparison for you rather than writing your own. Also, there is no usage of `stream`s in your answer.